# VBA - Why my CPU usage is not 100%

Tags: multithreading, excel, vba, cpu-speed

I used VBA under Excel in order to treat some data (input is .XML files).
XML file size is around 30MB and i have some computations on each entry of the file.
My computer ran on Windows 7 64 bits under Core i5 (4 core when I look in task manager) with 4GB of RAM

My question is: When my VBA script is running, why CPU usage not increase close to 100% ??
I can understand, may be, Excel do not use all the 4 cores of the CPU but why not on 1 core ?
(I have already tryed to change priority to 'real time')

I'm trying to find some solutions to speed up my script execution...
I have already tried to imporde my code with tips like : 
http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

Rework my design for splitting my script in thread to make tasks in parallel is the only solution ?

Thanks guys ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`VBA` runs in a single threaded apartment: yes that is wasteful when it comes to multi-core machines.

To benefit from parallelisation, one way is to (i) switch on Excel's multithreaded calculation mode *and* (ii) switch your architecture to using an `xll` rather than `VBA`.